# Handle a Char value from database

Tags: c#, asp.net, char

I save a char value in a table, under the type "char(10)".
When I try to get the values of a row in the table, I do the following:

```
DataTable table = MyAdoHelper.ExecuteDataTable(GlobalVar.dbName, Query);
```

The Ado helper is just a tool to extract the data from the table, nothing special about it.

When I do the next:

```
string MemberGender = (table.Rows[0]["member_gender"].ToString() == "m") ? "Male" : "Female";
```

But even when in the database there is a 'm', MemberGender is always "Female".

How am I supposed to handle the char value?

Comment: Please don't prefix your titles with "C# ASP.NET" and such. That's what the tags are for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Char` values are padded with whitespace, so what you actually get is `"m         "`. On the SQL Server, this behaviour can be turned on and off (for nullable chars) by using the [SET ANSI_PADDING](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187403.aspx) statement.

To fix this on the C# side, `Trim()` your value before comparing it:

```
... table.Rows[0]["member_gender"].ToString().Trim() == "m" ...
```

Alternatively, fix your database schema by changing the data type to `Char(1)` or `Varchar(10)`.

Answer (score 0):

"m" is not the same as "M". It might be the same in the database, but not in C#.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @Heinzi and @JonSaunders replies

Handle it at Database level? Reason is, it is faster in Database comparing it with Code Behind operations and case Non-Sensitivity is plus point there.

Assuming that the Database is `Sql Server`.

```
create table #t
(
  Nam char(10)
)

Insert into #t(Nam)Values('M')
Insert into #t(Nam)Values('F)

Select Case When Nam = 'm' Then 'Male' Else 'Female' End As Member_Gender From #t

Drop Table #t
```

---

### ResultSet

[image]